# How to set a <label for> to the id of selector located in a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

This is the part of my code I need to improve:

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
  <%= f.fields_for :goals do |goal| %>
    <%= goal.hidden_field :copm_id, value: goal.object.copm_id %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for='category'> Category/Subcategory</label>
        <%= goal.select :category_id, grouped_options_for_select(copm_category_list, goal.object.category_id), include_blank: true, id: 'category' %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Goal Description</label>
        <%= goal.text_area :description, rows: 2, cols: 70 %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

When inspecting the page in the browser and more precisely the drop down box "Category/Subcatgory" I noticed that the tag

```
<lablel for="category">
```

and the tag

```
<select name="copm[goals_attributes][0][category_id]" id="copm_goals_attributes_0_category_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="Self Care">
        <option value="1">Personal care</option>
        <option value="2">Functional mobility</option>
        <option value="3">Community management</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Productivity">
        <option value="4">Paid or unpaid work</option>
        <option value="5">Household management</option>
        <option value="6">School and/or play</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Leisure">
        <option value="7">Quiet recreation</option>
        <option value="8">Active recreation</option>
        <option value="9">Socialization</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

are different labels than I need.

I need to have either:

```
<lablel for="copm[goals_attributes][0][category_id]">
```

and "0" incremented accordingly for the second row and so on, or, this "id" below changed to a constant value no matter the row, something like this:

```
<select name="copm[goals_attributes][0][category_id]" id="category">
```

Any clue how to solve this problem will be very much appreciated since is important for some screen reader to fetch properly the labels associated with selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually setting the markup for the `label`, have you tried using `rails` form_builder helper method `label`?

So, instead of this:

`<label for='category'> Category/Subcategory</label>`

try using:

`<%= goal.label :category_id, 'Category/Subcategory' %>`

and see if it helps.

Refer to [FormBuilder#label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-label) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<td>
  <%= goal.label :category_id, 'your text for the label here' %>
  <%= goal.select :category_id, grouped_options_for_select(copm_category_list, goal.object.category_id), include_blank: true, id: 'category' %>
</td>
```

The same apply for `:description`, etc. Some documentation about the `label` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label